# Combining django templates with content editable for non-technical users

Tags: django, django-templates, content-management-system, wagtail, django-cms

We use django to generate HTML pages using templates which include javascript. Our website only consists out of a limited number of pages (creating new pages isn't a common use case) and we have people editing the content without python (and html) knowledge. Is there a way to have a simple user interface where non-technical editors can (in the best case) use a WYSIWYG editor to change the content (mainly text) of a template and a developer can build the page with html, css and javascript around it?

The problem we see with full CMS system like Wagtail and Django-CMS is that they don't give us the same flexibility to build the pages and don't offer the needed functionality to make our platform configurable (When setting up the system, a user can configure their specific instance of the system as many use cases have the same structure and only need specific configurations).

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to provide a helpful answer. I would say that Django (and frameworks that use it) do in fact give you a multitude of ways to build pages, you can determine the exact html structure you want to present. In regards to user specific configuration, Django and Wagtail both have the concepts of a 'site' and also a 'user' which can be extended in any arbitrary way. Or you could use environment variables for any kind of abstract config. It is true that any CMS will make some decisions for you, so you might find a less opinionated framework better.

Comment: If you want to roll your own basic editable content, this MDN page has a good overview and example code further down the page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content